# How to encode AndroidManifest.xml when creating apk

Tags: android, encoding, android-manifest

According to the requirements, I need to encode AndroidManifest.xml while creating apk so that no one can extract or hack my project information. How can I achieve this?

I searched on Google but didn't find any solution for this. I also tried  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777049/encode-decode-androidmanifest-xml-inside-apk) but got no solution.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16825266/1881611

Comment: @Ishrat Proguard is not my solutions...

Comment: why negative marking, i think its good questions

Comment: Yes you `have to encode AndroidManifest.xml` but the reason is not `so that no one can extract my project information`, maybe this is why you got the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`so that no one can extract my project information.`

I understand the need to make your code less likely to be hacked. But the `AndroidManifest` is not the place to do it. The `AndroidManifest` is the place where the application **publicly** declares what components it have, what permissions to access on the host OS and what hardware it uses from the host system.

Both the Android OS and Google Play Store **need** this information from the `AndroidManifest` so it can properly install it on the device and properly distribute the application.

So it's not possible!